# Why I'm still getting System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

My code is:

```
using( var ctxA = new AEntities())
using( var ctxB = new BEntities())
{
    var listOfA = (from A in AEntities.AEntity select A).ToList();
    var listOfB = (from B in BEntities.BEntity
                   where listOfA.Select( A = A.Id)contains(B.Id) 
                   select B).ToList();
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
 The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.
```

However, because of 'ToList' I already did a fetch in AEntity thats makes second query only about one of the contexts, did not?

How can a separate the two queries still using one list to query the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store just `IDs` into `listOfA`

```
 var listOfA = (from A in AEntities.AEntity select A.Id).ToList();
 var listOfB = (from B in BEntities.BEntity
               where listOfA.Contains(B.Id) 
               select B).ToList();
```

Comment: Selman, this worked. Thank you. But I could not figure out why this worked and my first try not. Can you explain? Other question: I need the list of entities of A too, how can avoid to do two queries on the database (one for the whole entity and one just to the ids)?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to know, the answer to my question was:

```
var listOfA = (from A in AEntities.AEntity select A.Id).ToList();
List<long> listOfIdsOfA = listOfA.Select( A=>A.id).ToList();
var listOfB = (from B in BEntities.BEntity
           where listOfIdsOfA.Contains(B.Id) 
           select B).ToList();
```

The only difference to Selman's answer was the creation of Id's list after the first query. That's why I need the whole entity too.